# Validate Email using validate_email package in azure databricks for 300k records result in timeout error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, email-validation, azure-databricks

I am trying to validate 300 000 mail ids using validate_email package and write it to a csv in azure databricks where i am getting timeout error.

```
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-365284720716518> in <module>()
----> 1 latest_dup_df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/MailResult/latest_dup_df_all")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    736             self._jwrite.save()
    737         else:
--> 738             self._jwrite.save(path)
    739 
    740     @since(1.4)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o548.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 16, 10.139.64.8, executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 456, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 149, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 445, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-3884158641112366>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/validate_email.py", line 134, in validate_email
    mx_hosts = get_mx_ip(hostname)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/validate_email.py", line 102, in get_mx_ip
    MX_DNS_CACHE[hostname] = DNS.mxlookup(hostname)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/lazy.py", line 56, in mxlookup
    l = dnslookup(name, qtype, timeout)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/lazy.py", line 38, in dnslookup
    result = Base.DnsRequest(name=name, qtype=qtype).req(timeout=timeout)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 324, in req
    self.sendUDPRequest(server)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 377, in sendUDPRequest
    raise first_socket_error
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 352, in sendUDPRequest
    r=self.processUDPReply()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/DNS/Base.py", line 135, in processUDPReply
    raise TimeoutError('Timeout')
DNS.Base.TimeoutError: Timeout
```

I am using Azure Databricks with python 3 and py3dns package. I am very new to spark and azure databricks. I also tried after setting DNS.defaults['server']=['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']. But still unable to resolve. Below is the code i tried. Is there an efficient way to validate 3 lakh mail ids. It is taking 7-8 hours and then job gets aborted and i get timeout error. I also tried with python 2. same issue.

```py
import DNS
DNS.defaults['server']=['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']

from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
from validate_email import validate_email
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

validate_mail_udf = udf(lambda x : validate_email(x,verify=True), BooleanType())
upd_df = upd_df.withColumn('is_mail_valid', validate_mail_udf(('mail_id')))

upd_df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/MailResult/")
```

Expected result is a new column named 'is_mail_valid' having boolean values representing whether the mail really exist or not for all 300 000 records and write the result df to a csv in azure databricks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark 2.3 and above version then you can use vectorized UDFs which will use PYarrow. Please follow below link for more details.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

Answer (score 0):

`validate_email(x,verify=True)` checks with the SMPT server whether the host exists. So you are essentially spamming the servers with 300 000 requests which is likely to block you on any of the stages and prevent further validation.

If your goal is to make sure those emails are valid, you can run this package with verify=False which is just going to run every email against a regex. This operation on 300k records should be really quick, no more than minutes.

If you want to verify whether an email actually exists, there is no good way to do this in bulk as email servers should be doing their best to prevent you from doing that :) `validate_email` takes a `timeout` parameter though, so you can try to increase that from default, but overall I'd advise very much against this approach.